# MongoDB .find() not returning filtered result

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe

My following code ignores the filter. I would like to filter only on country_code "US", and put the result into a dataframe. Yet, when I print a .head of the DF. It seems to ignore the filter.

My code:

```
data = records.find({}, {"_id":0, "created_at":1, "text":1, "place.country_code": "US"})
filtered_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(filtered_data.head())
```

Result:

```
                       created_at  ...                   place
0  Fri Aug 12 10:04:00 +0000 2016  ...  {'country_code': 'US'}
1  Fri Aug 12 10:04:02 +0000 2016  ...  {'country_code': 'US'}
2  Fri Aug 12 10:04:10 +0000 2016  ...  {'country_code': 'US'}
3  Fri Aug 12 10:04:21 +0000 2016  ...  {'country_code': 'AU'}
4  Fri Aug 12 10:04:30 +0000 2016  ...  {'country_code': 'US'}
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> db.collection.find(query, projection)

[Find method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections)

Your "mistake":

**First parameter:**
`query` - In your code: `find({})` (or `find()`) Returns **all** documents from a collection (Not only `US`).
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-all-documents-in-a-collection

**Second argument** use for `Projection parameter` (Specifies which **fields** to return - **Not** which documents to return).
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections

Add Query Criteria (`country_code: "US"`).

#### First Param - Add Query Criteria

**Data**

```
[
  {
    "country_code": "US"
  },
  {
    "country_code": "US"
  },
  {
    "country_code": "AU"
  }
]
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.find({
  country_code: "US"
})
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "country_code": "US"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "country_code": "US"
  }
]
```

#### Second Param (Projection)

For example **Exclude** `_id`.

Query:

```
db.collection.find({
  country_code: "US"
},
{
  _id: 0
})
```

**Result**:

```
[
  {
    "country_code": "US"
  },
  {
    "country_code": "US"
  }
]
```